# crlibm Library Installation Problem

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I am trying to install [crlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/download.html) using the installation instructions, which is as usual:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I get the following output:

```
Making install in scs_lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/scs_lib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/scs_lib'
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  libscs.a '/usr/local/lib'
 ( cd '/usr/local/lib' && ranlib libscs.a )
test -z "/usr/local/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 scs.h ../crlibm_config.h '/usr/local/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/scs_lib'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/scs_lib'
Making install in .
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4'
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  libcrlibm.a '/usr/local/lib'
 ( cd '/usr/local/lib' && ranlib libcrlibm.a )
test -z "/usr/local/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 crlibm.h '/usr/local/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4'
Making install in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/tests'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/tests'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c crlibm_testval crlibm_soaktest crlibm_testperf crlibm_blindtest crlibm_generate_test_vectors '/usr/local/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/tests'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/Desktop/crlibm-1.0beta4/tests'
```

The crlibm is actually a requirement for another program, which I fail to install. After I get the output above, I still fail to install it. That means, the `crlibm` was not installed successfully. Why do I get such a problem, do you also get such an issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: You should see files related to `crlibm` in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`. If there is a program that fails to compile, then either those two directories need to be added to the linker search directories and include directories respectively, or something else is going on.